# Why the coordinates of a location in streetview of Google Earth and Google Maps are different?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-earth, google-street-view

I am new to the Google Maps development and i have an issue struggling for some time.

The lat/long of a location in street view of google earth and google maps ( web browser) are not exactly matching.

Here are coordinate values of a location.

Google Maps Coordinates (in street view) : 51.81883690 -0.811931358 
Google Earth Coordinates (in street view): 51.81883889 -0.811955556

The difference begins at 5 decimal position but I am looking for precision till 6 decimal points.

Below is the methodology followed to derive the coordinates.

My requirement is to get the exact coordinates of an object (Pole, Manhole etc.) through Google Streetview. As I did not find option to place a marker on mouse click in Streetview (in Webbrowser), I had placed a marker around Street view camera location though javascript code `(code:: panorama.getPosition()+ some incremental values)` by directly assigning the lat/long to the marker. Also, dragged the marker to the location of interest. Now the marker's lat/long are noted down. But I observed that these coordinates not exactly matching with my base data.

Now tried with Google Earth as an alternative; I had placed the 'place mark' in street view at the same location as that of the above scenario and noted down the coordinates.

Coordinates from Streetview of google earth are better than that of Google Maps. So, what am i missing in google maps street view?

Sorry for long description of the scenario.

Any idea is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Thaviti Naidu G.

Comment: Where did you get he two different coordinates for the "Same point"? When they do become *different*?

Comment: At your latitude the 6th decimal points is equal at some centimeters... how you define the point.?

Comment: Roko C. Buljan: "Same Point" means same object and read its coordinates in both Earth Streetview and Maps Streetview. 
The object (pole) is viewed on both google earth street view and google maps street view maintaining same camera location, heading and pitch. Placed a 'Place Mark' in google earth and marker in google maps streetview.

Comment: To scaisEdge: 
Converted coordinates in meters for above mentioned points:

Maps Coordinates : X=481988 Y=214024

Earth Coordinates : X=481987 Y=214024

(Used http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi?f=conv for conversion)

So the deviation is by 1 meter. Can we minimize this? The reason i am worried is recordings in google earth are better ( though not exactly matching with my base data) but that of maps are not.